# SurveyMonkey API: Get shared data link

Tags: surveymonkey

I found the SurveyMonkey mobile display quite good. I am trying to better integrate it with my app. In particular, once the survey has been responded to, I want to show the "Results" (analyze page which has graphs of user responses).

One thing I realised is that user can't use the analyze url. One way to allow them to view is to create a "Shared Data Link".

I am wondering how can I do this using the SurveyMonkey API. How can I create a "Shared Data Link" using the API? Is there any other way to show the Analyze Page to users?

Answer (score 0):

Response from Survey Monkey team:
Unfortunately, our API doesn't currently offer any endpoints to generate a shared data page or quickly get the data which is contained within it.